# Does Flex support the data uri scheme?

Tags: apache-flex, base64, png, data-uri-scheme

I wish to pass many small PNG files as base64 encoded URIs within an XML response, but there seems to be no way to make flex present these images. I was thinking of the data uri scheme, but it appears not to be supported.

### Proposed solutions

1. Use Loader.LoadBytes

Tried it and it doesn't seem to work (none of the events are triggered).

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="1276" height="849" creationComplete="drawImage()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                import mx.utils.Base64Decoder;

                private function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
                        Alert.show("loader done");
            }

            private function errorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
                Alert.show("error" + e.toString());
            }

                public function drawImage() : void
                {
                        var b64png : String = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IAAAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1JREFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jqch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
                        var l : Loader = new Loader();

                        var decoder : Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
                        decoder.decode(b64png);
                        var bytes : ByteArray = decoder.flush();


                        l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
                        l.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);

                        l.loadBytes(bytes);

                }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Image x="10" y="10" width="155" height="118" id="image1"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decode the image data into a ByteArray then you can use Loader.loadBytes(byteArray) to load it as an image.

Comment: please take a look at my attempt of using Loader and tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could use something this to load the image:

```
var deco64:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder;

deco64.decode("base64StringWithTheImageData");

var arrBytes:ByteArray = deco64.toByteArray();

img.load(arrBytes);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the byte array returned from the decoder directly to the image's source property.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.utils.Base64Decoder;

            private function init():void {
                var b64png : String = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IAAAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1JREFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jqch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
                var decoder : Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
                decoder.decode(b64png);
                var bytes : ByteArray = decoder.flush();
                img.source = bytes;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Image id="img" />
</mx:Application>
```